# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-contrib

I use the built-in module in Django for tracking with user forgot password

I learned tutorial Django was 1.8 and I am with 2.2 now. I try to use that module but it not working

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    PasswordResetView,
    PasswordResetDoneView,
    PasswordResetConfirmView,
    PasswordResetCompleteView
)
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password/$', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='reset_password'),
    url(r'reset-password/done', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'reset-password/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'reset-password/complete/', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Exception Value:

> Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Exception Type:

> NoReverseMatch

Comment: can you also post how you are using the reverse function

Comment: @hendrikschneider It was a built-in function inside Django that I have learned from Youtube, but they use Django 1.8, but I don't know how it works as well :(

Comment: You're probably using that in an HTML or even in a Python file, can you show how you're using that? By its own, I don't think Django would complain about this URL

Comment: Please share your html template including the link to your `password_reset_confirm` view